# How to call a PHP from a mobile app?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, cordova

I have an HTML page that takes a login from user and authenticates and redirects to the different page. Now i converted this web-page to an app using phonegap app build function. Now i am trying to call the php thats on my server. What is the proper way to do so? Below is the code.

HTML

```
<script>
function PostData() {


    // 1. Create XHR instance - Start
    var xhr;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else {
        throw new Error("Ajax is not supported by this browser");
    }
    // 1. Create XHR instance - End

    // 2. Define what to do when XHR feed you the response from the server - Start
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
                document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    // 2. Define what to do when XHR feed you the response from the server - Start

    var userid = document.getElementById("userid").value;
    var pid = document.getElementById("pid").value;

    // 3. Specify your action, location and Send to the server - Start 


    xhr.open('POST', 'www.xyz.com/abc/login.php');

    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send("userid=" + userid + "&pid=" + pid);

    // 3. Specify your action, location and Send to the server - End

}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<form>
    <label for="userid">User ID :</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name ="userid" id="userid"  /><br/>
    <label for="pid">Password :</label><br/>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="pid" /><br><br/>



    <div id="div1">
    <input type="button" value ="Login" onClick="PostData()" />
    </div>


</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this jQuery.

```
    function PostData() {

           $.ajax({
                        url: "/ajax/login_check.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {userid : $("#userid").val(),pid : $("#pid").val()},
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (result) {
                            if(result.statu){
                              //Valide  Div Screen Show
                           }
                          else{
                                  //invalide Div Screen Show
                          }
                        }       
                    });

        }
```

check Valide Login use Check file

**login_check.php**

> ur Mysql And Php COde Put in this file.

```
if { //if valide Use than

    $responce['statu'] = "1";
    $responce['msg'] = "Login success.";
}

else{

    $responce['statu'] = "0";
    $responce['msg'] = "Invalide Use name & Pass";
    }
    echo json_encode ($responce);
    Exit;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code but it doesn't work. I tried to do as per the instructions. But nothing comes out.

Comment: in site  success: function (result) { console.log(result)} what Resurn is return in console log.??

Comment: Sorry for asking this but i hope you understood what i actually want to ask. If not please allow me to explain it to you.

Comment: can u plz explain in Detail what u need.??

Comment: The code I posted above works completely fine when used using a web browser. Now what I want is to convert this html page to a mobile application and call the PHP that is somewhere in my server. For example, in FACEBOOK. We just enter the username and password and it fetches all the details related to my profile on my mobile device. That is what I am trying to do. Fetch the information from the database and display it.

Comment: i hope are u femiler  with Phonegap.
can u plz tall me ur HTML Code is Single page.or u can Create Multiple HTML Pages.like login,profile,home,chat.

Comment: index.html page is a single page and then the data that i retrieve are re-directed to different pages. But the PHP for all the pages are same. I mean i have other html pages that send data to the same PHP.

Comment: Yes i pass the data using JS but its a simple echo in PHP thats hyperlinked to other HTML pages.

Comment: i think this is  not possible in phonegap technology.
in phonegap technology all HTML Contain in only onpage.

Comment: SO what would you suggest me to do. Shall i use jQuery mobile and use different pages for this thing??

Comment: frist create all HTML  in single page.u divide each module in particular Div.
like `<div id="login">`put login Form`</div>` `<div id="Home">`put home page html  code`</div>`
frist All Div is hide.only login Div Is Show.if login is seccuss than all other Div is hide and next login  Screen seccuss  Div show.
i am Develelope all phonegap App using this Technic.

Comment: can you please share a sample source code, if possible, on my email?

Comment: yes,if stackoverflow no any problem to send code in email,FB etc.
than u can send  email id.or contect me in FB/Gmail.

Comment: add the source code to your question, this isn't helpful for anyone if you discuss the solution outside from stackoverflow